# How could I mount a Asustor NAS (EXT4 Raid1) partition to uBuntu?

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid

I was using an Asustor NAS (Rubbish NAS) which was dead.  It was running a RAID 1 and the hard drives were in good health.  I unplugged the disk and put it onto an external USB adapter and do a `fdisk -l`.  I got the following result:

```
Device       Start         End     Sectors  Size Type

/dev/sdd1     2048      524287      522240  255M Linux filesystem

/dev/sdd2   524288     4718591     4194304    2G Linux RAID

/dev/sdd3  4718592     8912895     4194304    2G Linux RAID

/dev/sdd4  8912896 19532871679 19523958784  9.1T Linux RAID
```

I put in:
`mkdir /media/mymount`

Then I put in:
`mount /dev/sdd4 /media/mymount/`

However, the system replied:
`mount: /media/rav: special device /dev/sdd3 does not exist.`

I tried sdd1-sdd4 and they all gave me the same result.

What possibly is the problem?

Please help.

Comment: Please edit you question and use the formatting tools to make it. easier to read

Comment: What do you want to do? Recover data, wipe and reuse the drive, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Partitions are defined as RAID not as a proper filesystem. You can't directly mount them. You need to create a raid device first.

Try this how to: https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/05/08/how-to-mount-software-raid1-member-using-mdadm/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have also found that there are software you could install some software and then the partition could be mounted.  

By running the command below, the partition is accessible. 
apt-get install mdadm
apt-get install lvm2
mdadm -Asf && vgchange -a

Comment: That's exactly what create a raid device means!

Comment: Ops, sorry about that, then let me retry to use answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
I have also found that there are software you could install some software and then the partition could be mounted. By running the command below, the partition is accessible.

- apt-get install mdadm
- apt-get install lvm2
- mdadm -Asf && vgchange -a